# Submit button update one table and send details to another table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a form that modifies meta content of table 'wp_postmeta'.  I'm trying to figure out a way for the actions from the form to also INSERT into another table.

Is this possible? This is what I have and the data isn't inserting into the transaction table.

CURRENT FORM Submit button div:

```
<div class='inventory-management-form-item-holders inventory-management-submit-holder'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</div>
```

**"inventory-managment-submit" js SECTION:**

```
// submit form
jQuery("#submit").click(function(){
    // Change thw loading Gif url 
    jQuery('#the-results-holder').html("<img src='/wp-content/plugins/mcs-inventory-management/assets/images/loading_icon.gif' />");
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {'im-product-id': theProductId, 'status-quantity': jQuery('#status-quantity').val(), 'status-action': jQuery('#im-action-box').val(), 'status-location': jQuery('#status-location').val(), 'status-move-location': jQuery('#status-move-location').val()},
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/inventory-management-process/",
        processData: true,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#the-results-holder').html(""); 
            jQuery('#status-stock').val(data.stock);
            jQuery('#status-res').val(data.res);
            jQuery('#status-prepro').val(data.prepro);
            jQuery('#status-clean').val(data.clean);
            jQuery('#status-quantity').val("0");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            jQuery('#the-results-holder').html(""); 
            jQuery('#the-results-holder-error').html("There has been an error!"); 
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**this is where I attempt to perform an INSERT what the form into the transaction table?**

```
<form name='inventory-management' id='inventory-management-form' method="POST" action='<?php $transaction ?>'>


<?php
$product= $_POST['part-number'];
$action= $_POST['status-action'];
$from_location= $_POST['status-location'];
$to_location= $_POST['status-move-location'];
$qty= $_POST['status-quantity'];


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $transaction = "INSERT INTO mcs_inventory_transactions (id,product,action,from_location,to_location,qty) VALUES ('','$product','$action','$from_location','$to_location','$qty')";
 $result = mysql_query($transaction);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you actually have a form element with name submit?

Comment: Well for one thing, you're missing a `$` for `'to_location',` in your values, so fix that. It won't stop it from being inserted, so the error is elsewhere.

Comment: But that shouldn't cause the insert to fail, it should just insert a wrong location.

Comment: Plus, do check for possible errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: ***Woah there cowboy** (or girl)* - (*for one thing*) you don't have an (input) submit button named `submit`. You have a `<button>` - Your conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` is based on it.

Comment: Squire, that code just does not work. Be honest about the code you are running.

Comment: So the 'submit' in the isset should be set to 'inventory-managment-submit'?

Comment: No, either remove the conditional statement, or change your button to `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">`

Comment: Please try to echo the value of $_POST['submit']; . Check weather it has a value or not

Comment: I have edited my answer please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Change your js to

```
  JS
// submit form

    jQuery("#inventory-management-submit").click(function(){
        // Change thw loading Gif url 
        jQuery('#the-results-holder').html("<img src='/wp-content/plugins/mcs-inventory-management/assets/images/loading_icon.gif' />");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {'im-product-id': theProductId, 'status-quantity': jQuery('#status-quantity').val(), 'status-action': jQuery('#im-action-box').val(), 'status-location': jQuery('#status-location').val(), 'status-move-location': jQuery('#status-move-location').val(),submit: "test"},
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/inventory-management-process/",
            processData: true,
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('#the-results-holder').html(""); 
                jQuery('#status-stock').val(data.stock);
                jQuery('#status-res').val(data.res);
                jQuery('#status-prepro').val(data.prepro);
                jQuery('#status-clean').val(data.clean);
                jQuery('#status-quantity').val("0");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                jQuery('#the-results-holder').html(""); 
                jQuery('#the-results-holder-error').html("There has been an error!"); 
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: [`Read my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388535/submit-button-update-one-table-and-send-details-to-another-table#comment39596107_25388535)

Comment: No problemo. However, the OP's question for me, is too unclear. Too many potential things wrong with it and code we do not see.

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong:

```
$transaction= if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

should be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

Comment: I totally overlooked that. However, OP doesn't have a submit button called `submit`. Edit: OP changed the question. Btw, I did not DV.

Comment: thanks.  I noticed I had that section incorrect. see changes.  Should the 'submit' in the $_POST be set to 'inventory-managment-submit'?

Comment: ok there are a lot of problems here.  First off you have assigned the variables you insert to be hard-coded strings, not the $_POST results of a form submit eg `$product = $_POST['im-product-id']`.  Second, if the id field is an autoincrement type you don't want to include it in your insert query.  Third you probably don't have an `input name='submit'` field.  I suggest you comment out all that code, replace it with `var_dump($_POST);die();` and see what your form is actually submitting.  Use an if condition that contains one, some or all of the required fields from the form.

Comment: OK.  Using code that is above, it is adding to the database, however, now it is not making changes to the other table.

when I add id="submit" to <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit">  It moves the inventory but doesn't write to the table.

Comment: any ideas why the "id" in the input is causing the query not to run?  The echo $_POST['submit']; doesn't return anything when there is an "id" in there.

Comment: I don't know why but it's irrelevant, you don't need id="submit" in your input tag - get rid of it.  The php key/value pairs in $_POST are generated by the `name` of each input and its corresponding `value`.

Comment: without the "id" value, the jquery does not run.

Comment: Ah true enough, I missed that you were assigning the ajax function to the click of that button.  There are ways to avoid that (use onsubmit event of form for example) but never mind.  Check Uktarsh's answer he added in `submit: "test"` to the `data` property of the ajax object, that should make it work.

Comment: I tried adding submit: "test" or 'submit': "test" to the jq without any luck.